# store result in a column from fortran 77

Tags: plot, fortran, fortran77

I am converting one of my codes to fortran 77, and I am having a problem regarding storing the results.

I used the following code

```
OPEN(UNIT=21, FILE='name.TXT', STATUS='REPLACE')
WRITE(UNIT = 21,*) results
CLOSE(UNIT=21)
```

and then  load the file name.txt in Matlab to plot. However, the result is written in file as two-dimensional array, so the matlab recognizes the entries in incorrect order. I think the solution for that is to write the result in the name.txt as one-dimensional array.

Can anyone have any suggestion about writing the result from fortran as an array. For example, I would like to get a file in which entries are ordered as

1  2   3   4   5  6  7   8   9   10

other than

1  2   3   4   5
6  7   8   9   10.

Of course if you know any better way to plot the result obtained from Fortran 77, it will be useful for me too.

By the way I am working on UNIX.

Thanks

Comment: Is result a 2D or 1D array?

Answer (score 0):

When you use free-format output (better known as the

```
*
```

format specifier), Fortran leaves the details of the output up to the compiler. One such detail is the number of characters in a single row. Most compilers will wrap output to a new line after a certain number of characters, and when you use free-formatting you have no way to affect this. So it's not really being written as a 'two-dimensional array', it's being written out sequentially and periodically moving to a new line when it runs out of 'space' (as defined by the compiler. Try using a format like this:

```
WRITE(UNIT=21, '(I)') results
```

With the format above, the compiler is forced to print the variable **results** as an integer (or a bunch of integers) and, since there is no line break instructions in the format, it will print out all of the elements of **results** on one line. In fact, it will print them out with no spaces in between, which is probably not what you want. Add an 'X' field identifier to put a space in between each integer.

```
WRITE(UNIT=21, '(I, X)') results
```

That should give you a single unbroken row of integers in your file. If you are instead using floating point variables, replace the **I** for an **F**.

Check out this page for further explanation on Fortran77 formatting:
http://www.oc.nps.edu/~bird/oc3030_online/fortran/io/io.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a format with an explicit number of integers (of fixed length):

```
WRITE(UNIT = 21, '(100i5)') return
```

If the number of elements in the array is known you could use an implicit loop:

```
WRITE(UNIT = 21, '(100i5)') ( return(j), j=1,n )
```